# PrimeNG tree table tree vertical expansion lines

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I have a large PrimeNG tree table that I want to add lines to like a tree. The purpose is to make the depth more clear as you scroll further down into the table. Below is an example of what I want:
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbEKa.png)

How would I add icons to the left of each toggle icon, that are right-justified next to the icon, and that connect to each other to demonstrate the tree structure of the treetable? Essentially I want to add a p-tree to the first column of the p-treetable that allows the other columns to still be visible when expanded.

I tried getting icons on the left of the toggle, but they are left justified.
[treetable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE0zB.png)

I also tried to put the icons within the p-treeTableToggler tags, but they are not visible when I do that.

```
<p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-gears"></i>
</p-treeTableToggler>
```

In any case, I have no idea how to try to get the lines to join the icons to demonstrate the tree table's hierarchy.